# How to wake-up remote IIS webserver using dd-wrt shell scripting

Tags: bash, router, shell-script, dd-wrt

#### The problem:

I have some asp.net websites hosted on IIS ( at a local hosting company). Now if nobody access them during aprox. 20 minutes, the IIS is going into sleep mode, so the first next request will wake up the server but it will take some time so it's very annoying for the user.

#### The Question:

How to wake up my websites using a script from my dd-wrt?

I guess some sort of sending an HTTP request each X minutes.

I don't have knowledge in bash scripting, if somebody could help me, i'll be very happy. Thank you

#### Note: I cannot overwrite the master config of IIS.

Comment: what. why is the server going to sleep?

Comment: It's an IIS feature to free out unused resources. So it gets to idle if nobody access the websites.

Comment: I suppose you're looking for something more complicated than a cronjob that does a wget?

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not initiated how to use Cron. If the result will be achieved anyway, it really doesn't matter by which tool. Can you illustrate a sample?

Comment: @Christian, knock yourself out. I'm developing on bash/AIX, so I may not have the exact resources a dd-wrt (probably Linux) environment has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems so far that you want something that will hit your website every so often to keep it from sleeping. This will affect your analytics, but here goes:

#### keepitalive.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# call this script with cronjob:
# 0,15,30,45 * * * * /home/username/keepsitealive.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
outdir=~/
cd $outdir
wget http://www.example.com/index.html
rm $outdir/index.html
```

#### The cronjob

For the entry in cron (if you have access to that on a dd-wrt router; don't know much about those), use something like this:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /home/username/keepsitealive.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If you have a terminal to the device (that includes an ssh interactive shell), you can usually edit cron by running as superuser `crontab -e`, but that may be slightly dependent on which exact flavor of Linux it's on.

A quick explanation of the cronjob I listed here for you:

```
0,15,30,45    #minutes during each hour. So every 15 minutes.
* (first one) #every hour
*             #every day-of-month
*             #every month
*             #every day-of-week (usually not used when day-of-month is used, for example)
/home/user/keepitalive.sh #the command. Can be a series of shell commands and not just a script. Separate commands with a semicolon ; and keep them all on the same line.
> /dev/null   #after a command: redirects stdout to null-device (hides output) because if you don't, superuser will get emails and it's annoying.
2>&1          #sends stderr to same place as stdout, which you probably want pointing to /dev/null. This suppresses error messages from hitting superuser email.
```

For thorough tutorials using cron, google it. Here's a link to get you started: http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll give it a try right now!

Comment: Ooh, if you're new to scripting, etc., you may not be immediately aware that you need to set the execute flag on the file. As the owner of the file (or superuser), run `chmod 744 /home/user/keepitalive.sh` which will set flags rwxr--r-- (r/w/execute) for owner, owner's group, everyone in that order.

Comment: Could you please explain the `rm $outdir/index.html`, are you trying to remove a file index.html from outdir? What if the url is, lets say top domain like example.com ?

Comment: Well, I chose to specify which file since I don't know the defaults for your site. If you were to say `http://yoursite.com/` you would need to know the default homepage it sends to the requesting agent. You can specify whatever you wish. Especially since you know your site, tell this to grab any valid page or whichever page you prefer.

Comment: @Christian, and the rm command just cleans up the downloaded file, since you have no use for it on the local device (the router). This will help prevent clutter and potential clobbering (attempts to overwrite files that are usually prevented and incur error messages).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14797/discussion-between-christian-and-bgstack).